# how to get IndexPath.row in didFinishLoading in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to get IndexPath.row outside cellforrowAtIndexPath method i.e on didFinishLoading. My code is like this

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [myNSMDataFromServer mutableBytes] length:[myNSMDataFromServer length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"loginStatus =%@",loginStatus);
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:loginStatus error:&parseError];
    NSLog(@"JSON DICTIONARY = %@",xmlDictionary);
    recordResult = [xmlDictionary[@"success"] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)recordResult);
    NSDictionary* Address=[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"soap:Envelope"];
    NSLog(@"Address Dict = %@",Address);
    NSDictionary *new =[Address objectForKey:@"soap:Body"];
    NSLog(@"NEW DICT =%@",new);
    NSDictionary *LoginResponse=[new objectForKey:@"TFMComplaints_GetNewResponse"];
    NSLog(@"Login Response DICT =%@",LoginResponse);
    NSDictionary *LoginResult=[LoginResponse objectForKey:@"TFMComplaints_GetNewResult"];
    NSLog(@"Login Result =%@",LoginResult);
    if(LoginResult.count>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Login Result = %@",LoginResult);
        NSLog(@"Login Result Dict =%@",LoginResult);
         NSString *teststr =[[NSString alloc] init];
        teststr =[LoginResult objectForKey:@"text"];
        NSLog(@"Test String Value =%@",teststr);
        NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];
        NSLog(@"Now String is =%@",string);
        NSData *data =[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError* error;
        NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [closetbl indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *firstObj = [array objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];

        idarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        idarray=[firstObj valueForKey:@"Key"];
        NSLog(@"Result Array =%@",idarray);
}
```

I am getting only one value that is on 0.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: for what purpose u want to this in didFinishLoading method?

Comment: Please explain more.....

Comment: NSDictionary *firstObj = [array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

Comment: @ashmi123 I am getting only value at 0 Index in dictionary. but there is 19 object.

Comment: If you want indexPath of selected row then you can do `[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`  So, ask cleat so that someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a for loop for array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{
    //where i will be the index path. You can use it like this 
    NSDictionary *firstObj = [array objectAtIndex:i];

}
```

In your case you can use it like this:

```
idarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++){
    NSDictionary *firstObj = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    [idarray addObject:[firstObj valueForKey:@"Key"]];
    NSLog(@"Result Array =%@",idarray);

  }
```

Comment: Do you need selected Index?

Comment: I need all Index.

Comment: So I have mentioned you you just need to add amor loop.

Comment: It Shows error "No visible interface for "NSMutableArray" declare the selector addObject: value for key"

Answer (score 1):

`NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`

For more details follow: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Muju Have breakpoint at `NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [closetbl indexPathForSelectedRow];` and check the values for `closetbl `, `selectedIndexPath.section` and `selectedIndexPath.row`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the indexpath and from this indexpath you can get also the selected cell.

```
let indexPath = self.tblObj.indexPathForSelectedRow!

let currentCell = self.tblObj.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! YourTableViewCell
```